# Import .docx files as an es module in javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js, docx, esmodules

Is there anyway to import .docx files as ES modules?

Like this:

```js
import template from "@lib/assets/template.docx"
```

I've searched a lot for the past months and I couldn't get a direct answer. I'm using it to import a document file so that I can use docxtemplater to create me a document, base on that template. I can use it on dev environment but not on prodcution. I want to build an app and it doesn't need to be on the internet, I just want it to work and also in Typescript it gives me an error of 'Cannot find module'

I tried using this

```js
import template from '../../../../public/docs/Template.docx'
```

for the development environment but when build it, it does not work.

Here are some context of the code.

```js
async function generateDocument(temp : any, templatePath : any) {
        // load the document template into docxtemplater
      
        try {
            setLoading(true)
          
            let response = await fetch(templatePath);
            let data = await response.arrayBuffer();
    
            let zip = new PizZip(data);
    
            let templateDoc = new Docxtemplater(zip, {
                paragraphLoop: true,
                linebreaks: true
            })
    
            templateDoc.render(temp);
    
            let generatedDoc = templateDoc.getZip().generate({
                type: "base64",
                mimeType: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document",
                compression: "DEFLATE"
            })
  
            
            
      
            alert("Saved Succuessfully See Reports/forms")
        } catch (error) {
            console.log('Error: ' + error);
            setLoading(false)
        }
      }
```

I think it's from the fetch API, but I don't really know. Basically I just wanted to have an absolute path on my .docx file so that I can manipulate it just like the code above.